# How to find GO button keycode using Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, dom-events

Anyone have idea, how to find GO button's keycode using Javascript in Android browser.

Answer (score 3):

The 'Go', 'Enter/Return', 'Search', ... keys are all synonyms of KeyEvent.[KEYCODE_ENTER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_ENTER)
The KeyboardView only changes its appearance based on EditText inputMethod options.

All result in the character 10 / 0x0A to be produced.

Note that it will be caught and interpreted by webview internal logic unless you catch it yourself by overriding onKeyDown in your activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)){
       mWebView.loadUrl('javascript:handleEnterKey()');
       return true;
   }
   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```